# angular multidimensional array assignment

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

Working with Angular 5.

What I am trying to do is to assign in array a multidimensional array.

What is working with PHP?

```
$arM = array();
$arM["20/02/2020"][1] = ["name"=> 'my name', "id"=> 1];
```

the output of this is:

```
Array
(
    [20/02/2020] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => my name
                    [id] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

In angular when I am doing this is not working. Example:

```
let data:any = [];
data["20/02/2020"][1] = myArray;
```

How can I achieve the same result of PHP's?

Comment: Please show how the expected output will look like

Comment: Like php's result as shown above or in any similar form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0):

Like this maybe?

```js
let data = {}; // Object (with keys), not array
data["20/02/2020"] = { name : "my name", id : 1 };

console.log(data);
```

Comment: something like this but you missed the key of the object which I need to be 1 not 0.

Comment: What does that mean? Where did I set an object with a key "0" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
let data:Object = {
      "20/02/2020":[
         {"name":"my name", "id": 1}, 
         {"name":"my name2", "id": 2},
         {"name":"my name3", "id": 3}
      ]
 };
```